# Rails Mailer: "No route matches {}" when trying to use URL helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, actionmailer

I can't get the `*_url` helpers to work in my mailers.

For example, I have `resources :pages` in my `routes.rb`.

But when trying to use any of the helpers in a mailer view, it's always telling me:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError
No route matches {}
```

The following tests may give some more hints...

```
root_url                # results in No route matches {}
pages_url               # results in No route matches {}
page_url                # results in No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages"}, missing required keys: [:id]
page_url 1              # results in No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages", :locale=>1}, missing required keys: [:id]
page_url 1, locale: :en # results in No route matches {}
```

I have no idea how to debug and fix this any further.

Comment: How did you use these urls? with `link_to`?

Comment: You're right, I think it was just a stupid mistake on my side. It's working now like this: `link_to 'page 1', page_url(1, locale: :de)`!

Comment: OK :). `link_to` requires two parameters I guess you only passed one

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I used the `mail_to` helper in the same view, and while `mail_to` only needs one parameter (it simply uses it for both link text and target), the `link_to` always needs two parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This likely happened because `link_to` requires two parameters. I came across this issue when using `link_to` in a text-based mailer, so here's how I solved it:

Instead of this:

`Click here to verify this user: <%= link_to @user %>`

Try this:

`Click here to verify this user: <%= users_url(@user) %>`

Comment: Isn't this still one parameter with a resource url?

Comment: This also fixes the issue: `Click here to verify this user: <%= link_to users_url(@user), users_url(@user) %>`